# Google Play email address for users who left a comments

Tags: google-play, google-plus, google-play-services

Is any way to get an email address for users who left a comments to a certain app at Google Play store ?

Or may be there is some way to get a user email address by Google Plus user id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not possible and its on purpose to prevent spam email harvests.

You would need to add them on google+ to your circles. then you can send hangouts and even email them by typing their google+ name in web gmail.

see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3294854